# Skrollr.js: Using fixed and dynamic height slides possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I'm working on a one-page-layout and used skrollr for it, which works quite nicely. However, now I've encountered a slight problem. With the desktop version of the site everything fits neatly on the screen, but on a mobile device the content of some slides does not fit at all, so I'd like to use a variable height for those slides, but I can't get it working, the content is always cut off at the window height / overlaid by the next slide. Is there a way to remedy that? Or am I trying something impossible here?

Thanks + greetz,

Tox